# Python .split() having trouble with txt line

Tags: python, list, split

I am trying to split lines in a txt file but having the following problem:

```
with open("KARDEX.txt", 'r', encoding="latin-1") as file:
    data = []
    for line in file:
        data.append(line)

print(data[0])
>>ÿþ#     Número de artículo      Descripción del artículo        Clase de operación      Código de deudor/acreedor       Nombre de deudor/acreedor 

d = print(data[0].split("     "))
>> ['ÿþ#\x00', '\x00N\x00ú\x00m\x00e\x00r\x00o\x00 \x00d\x00e\x00 \x00a\x00r\x00t\x00í\x00c\x00u\x00l\x00o\x00', '\x00D\x00e\x00s\x00c\x00r\x00i\x00p\x00c\x00i\x00ó\x00n\x00 \x00d\x00e\x00l\x00 \x00a\x00r\x00t\x00í\x00c\x00u\x00l\x00o\x00', '\x00C\x00l\x00a\x00s\x00e\x00 \x00d\x00e\x00 \x00o\x00p\x00e\x00r\x00a\x00c\x00i\x00ó\x00n\x00']
```

Comment: The split function is used to split a string into an array. You are trying to split an array. Also, what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split by 2 or more spaces then use:

```
re.split(r" {2,}", st)
```

---

**st:**

```
st = "ÿþ#     Número de artículo      Descripción del artículo        Clase de operación      Código de deudor/acreedor       Nombre de deudor/acreedor"
```

---

re.split(r" {2,}", st)

---

**Output:**

```
['ÿþ#',
 'Número de artículo',
 'Descripción del artículo',
 'Clase de operación',
 'Código de deudor/acreedor',
 'Nombre de deudor/acreedor']
```